# How to get Quartz Composer working on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, macos

I'd like to install `Quartz Composer`. So I head to [Downloads Center](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and download `Additional Tools for Xcode 9` package which contains `Quartz Composer`.

After copying the app elsewhere, launching it, and clicking `Get Started` I get this error below. How do I get it working?

[image: Quartz Composer error]

Comment: Sorry that I have no solution. I only wanted to note, that the Bluetooth Explorer also doesn't work. I think we will have to wait for an update...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest (its still old) graphics tools here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

The DMG for XCode 7.2 contains a version of Quartz Composer that runs on High Sierra.

Comment: That actually works!

Answer (score 1):

For recent operating systems and XCode versions, I was able to load Quartz Composer directly from the latest Additional Tools download that works with that machine's XCode version.

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
2. Search for Additional Tools
3. Download the version corresponding to your XCode. For example:

   - For 10.12.6, XCode 9.2, download **Additional Tools for XCode 9**
   - For 10.13, XCode 10.1, download **Additional Tools for XCode 10.1**
4. Quartz Composer is in the Graphics subfolder, along with Quartz Composer Visualizer. Copy to Applications alongside XCode -- or wherever you prefer to install dev tools.

Comment: Looks like this is true for me as well